# Using LocationListener (with google play service) as service consume too much battery (Android 4.4.2)

Tags: gps, android-location

I have a service that returns the current position every 30 seconds, my problem is that the service consumes about 40% of the battery. The GPS icon is always active, even if I increase the time interval. I see this problem with my Nexus 4 android 4.4.2. Once the callback  OnLocationChanged is called, the GPS is awake all the time and this consumes the entire battery. With my other Phone Nexus One android 2.2.3 , I do not see this problem, the GPS turns on every 30 seconds and turns off. And I have no battery consommation. The service use Location Request, with .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY), excepted to use GPS and Network and is not the case. I thinks there is a problem with android 4.4.2 or is Google play service

Here my service code:

```
public class MyServiceGpsDebug extends Service implements       
 GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,    
 GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener 
 {

     IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

      private LocationClient mLocationClient;
      private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
      // Flag that indicates if a request is underway.
      private boolean mInProgress;

      private Boolean servicesAvailable = false;

      public class LocalBinder extends Binder 
      {
            public MyServiceGpsDebug getServerInstance() 
            {
                return MyServiceGpsDebug.this;
            }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() 
      {
          super.onCreate();

          mInProgress = false;
          // Create the LocationRequest object
          mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
          // Use high accuracy
          mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
          // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
          mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL);
          // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
          mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FASTEST_INTERVAL);

          servicesAvailable = servicesConnected();
          mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);   
      }

          private boolean servicesConnected() 
      {

          // Check that Google Play services is available
          int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

          // If Google Play services is available
          if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) 
          {
              return true;
          } 
          else
          {
              return false;
          }
      }

      public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
      {
          super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

          if(!servicesAvailable || mLocationClient.isConnected() || mInProgress)
            return START_STICKY;

          setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
          if(!mLocationClient.isConnected() || !mLocationClient.isConnecting() && !mInProgress)
          {
            appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Started", Constants.LOG_FILE);
            mInProgress = true;
            mLocationClient.connect();
          }

          return START_STICKY;
      }

      private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded()
      {
            if(mLocationClient == null) 
                  mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
      }

          @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
      {
          // Report to the UI that the location was updated
          String msg = Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," + Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
          Log.d("debug", msg);
          // Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          appendLog(msg, Constants.LOCATION_FILE);
      }

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
      {
            return mBinder;
      }

      public String getTime() 
      {
            SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            return mDateFormat.format(new Date());
      }

      public void appendLog(String text, String filename)
      {       
             File logFile = new File(filename);
             if (!logFile.exists())
             {
                try
                {
                   logFile.createNewFile();
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
             try
             {
                //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
                BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
                buf.append(text);
                buf.newLine();
                buf.close();
             }
             catch (IOException e)
             {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy()
      {
          // Turn off the request flag
          mInProgress = false;
          if(servicesAvailable && mLocationClient != null)
          {
                mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
                // Destroy the current location client
                mLocationClient = null;
          }
          // Display the connection status
          // Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Stopped", Constants.LOG_FILE);
          super.onDestroy();  
      }


      @Override
      public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) 
      {

          // Request location updates using static settings
          mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
          appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Connected", Constants.LOG_FILE);

      }

      @Override
      public void onDisconnected() 
      {
          // Turn off the request flag
          mInProgress = false;
          // Destroy the current location client
          mLocationClient = null;
          // Display the connection status
          // Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Disconnected", Constants.LOG_FILE);
      }


      @Override
      public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) 
      {
        mInProgress = false;

          if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) 
          {

          // If no resolution is available, display an error dialog
          } else {

          }
      }


      public final class Constants 
      {

            // Milliseconds per second
            private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
            // Update frequency in seconds
            private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 60;
            // Update frequency in milliseconds
            public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
            // The fastest update frequency, in seconds
            private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 60;
            // A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
            public static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
            // Stores the lat / long pairs in a text file
            public static final String LOCATION_FILE = "sdcard/location.txt";
            // Stores the connect / disconnect data in a text file
            public static final String LOG_FILE = "sdcard/log.txt";


            /**
             * Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability
             */
            private Constants() {
                throw new AssertionError();
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with Nexus 4. My app has a service which uses location updates (fusion location or android providers, not both). Everything works OK for all android phones but in Nexus4 after some time the phone gets hot and slow even if i kill the app (through DDMS, 100% stopped). The only solution is to kill Google play services .
I think that there is a bug in play services for nexus 4. There is a dirty solution to kill  Google Play Services every 30mins for example if phone=nexus4, but i do not know if it is possible

Comment: Finally some one with the same problem as me :). There already two issue on this bug:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=52236    and this one https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=gps&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=64998#makechanges

Comment: But there is no answer, waiting for the fix.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i wanted to add a comment (not an answer)... my fault :-)

Comment: @benomma777, the problem seems to be solved after updating to Google Play Services 4.4.52. Automatic update was not ready for my N4 so got the apk from XDA ([link](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/apk-compendium-google-play-services-4-4-52-for-all-densities-and-the-rest-of-this-weeks-updates/))(for nexus 4 you need the -036 version). Just did a stress test (3G, gps update with similar to yours values) for an hour, everything seems good.  Haven't update the library of Play Services to the app as it is not yet availabe in android SDK manager

Comment: @benomma777, I think that in your case the GPS will stay On. In gingerbread case things work differently as can be seen in system logs when using GPS. Perhaps you have to stop location in onLocationChanged and restart with some timer. Also please set mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(5) //e.g. 5 meters  to save a lot of battery. This means that the GPS may not take a new value if user has not moved 5 meters away.

Comment: I just recieved 4.4.3 verion on my nexus 4, i will try to do some test and upgrade my service.